# async await function return blank array problem in node js

Tags: node.js

sessionFilter.js

```
'use strict';
const knex = require('../config/database')

class SessionFilter{
    async setPermissionFilterArray(data){
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try { 
                const sql_data = await knex.select(knex.raw(sql));
                var all_permission = []; 
                sql_data.forEach(function(val) {
                    if (all_permission[val.event_ref] === undefined) all_permission[val.event_ref] = [];
                    if (all_permission[val.event_ref][val.event_slug] === undefined) all_permission[val.event_ref][val.event_slug] = [];
                    all_permission[val.event_ref][val.event_slug][val.event_slug_key] = {
                        permission:val.permission,
                        no_permission:val.no_permission,
                        sql_where_clause:val.sql_where_clause
                    }
                });
                resolve(all_permission);
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error.message);
            }
        })
    }
}   
module.exports = SessionFilter;
```

server.js

```
const filter = new SessionFilter();
const set_permission_filter_array = await filter.testFunction(data);
console.log(set_permission_filter_array);
return res.json(set_permission_filter_array);
```

when i console set_permission_filter_array variable showing data well but when i return set_permission_filter_array variable showing blank array at frontend. how can i get data? please help me.

Comment: `async` functions always return a promise, so you don't need to create one yourself using the Promise constructor. Also, the executor function (function passed to the Promise constructor) should NOT be an `async` function.

Comment: @Yousaf thanks for comments. but i tried without promise and same result comes.

Comment: See if [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994496/why-does-express-js-return-an-empty-array-when-using-res-send/48022515) helps you debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your function will automaticaly return a promise because of the async keyword.
This promise will be resolved at the `return all_permission;` statement.

```
class SessionFilter{
   async setPermissionFilterArray(data){        
       try { 
           //don't know were this sql var comes from
           const sql_data = await knex.select(knex.raw(sql));             
           var all_permission = []; 
           sql_data.forEach((val) => { 
               ... 
           });
           return all_permission;
       } catch (error) {
           throw error;
       }        
   }
}
```

Then you can get the result of your promise using async await keywords like this :

```
const set_permission_filter_array = await setPermissionFilterArray(data);
```

Comment: OP is already getting the result from the `setPermissionFilterArray` function. Yes, the Promise constructor should be removed but that's not the cause of the problem here.

Comment: return res.json(set_permission_filter_array); 
showing following error.
(node:2092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: set_permission_filter_array is not defined

Comment: Still blank array return. but when i push a single value in all_permission EXAMPLE:- all_permission[val.enent_ref].push(val.event_slug) then data show perfectly. but multidimensional array return blank.