# Adding properties to javascript array at the moment of declaration?

Tags: javascript, arrays, properties

I know that we can add properties to an already defined array like this,

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3];

array1.prop1 = 'first';
console.log(array1);  // [ 1, 2, 3, prop1: 'first' ]
```

My question is that is there any **syntax** for doing the same thing while declaring the array? Something similar to this,

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, prop1: 'first']  // SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

P.S. Some may say adding properties to arrays is not considered a good practice. That is actually not the answer I'm looking for. I'm just asking about the *possibility* of doing something like this.

Comment: Note that "extra" properties on array objects are fine, but if you serialize the array with `JSON.stringify()` they won't be included in the result.

Comment: And no, there's no initializer syntax for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526896/476

Comment: Note that the output of console.log() will only contain the property on Chrome. All other browsers will only show the actual contents of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an object and assign this to an array.

```js
var array1 = Object.assign([], { 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, prop1: 'first' });

console.log(array1);
console.log(array1.prop1);
```

Comment: Would it be easier to read if you just spread [1,2,3]? As in `{ ...[1,2,3], prop1: 'first' }`

Comment: [ಠ_ಠ](http://frontsightpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/speechless.png)

Comment: @Kobe, yes, or no, because this code should never be used. it is for educational purpose only.

Comment: @deceze, please see above comment.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sure, I only mentioned it to make it easier to write, not for actual use :P