# How to properly type a .map loop argument

Tags: javascript, typescript

So I have a timezone list and has a type of the following:

```
type TimezoneListType = {
   label: string;
   name: string;
   offset: number;
   lower?: string;
   offsetString?: string;
 };

const TIMEZONE_LIST: TimezoneListType[] = [
  {
    label: 'Niue',
    name: 'Pacific/Niue',
    offset: -11,
  },
  {
    label: 'Pago Pago',
    name: 'Pacific/Pago_Pago',
    offset: -11,
  },
  //... and so on
];

const TIMEZONE_NAME_MAP: any = {};

const TIMEZONE_MAP = TIMEZONE_LIST.map((item) => {
  const positive = item.offset >= 0;
  const hour = item.offset | 0;
  const minute = (item.offset - hour) * 60;
  return TIMEZONE_NAME_MAP[item.name] = {  // typescript is screaming in this line. if try to change the `any` to `TimezoneListType`
    ...item,
    lower: item.label.toLowerCase(),
    offsetString: 'something',
  };
});
```

on the lower end of the code you'll see that I'm transforming timezone list to have keys of `item.name` then adding some property `lower` and `offsetString`.

My problem is `item.name` is giving me:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type number ts(7015)

on both `item` and `name` when I hover at them. And I'm not sure how to type it correctly.

EDIT: Ideal result of the transformation is the photo below: [image: TIMEZONE_MAP_NAME]

I've just put `any` on the map argument like `TIMEZONE_LIST.map((item: any)`

**Update:** I've changed my object declaration type to 
`const TIMEZONE_NAME_MAP: Record<string, TimezoneListType> = {};` 
seems to work but I don't understand why? and Now the other part of my program is screaming as I've exported it to other places so I can use it like TIMEZONE_NAME_MAP.filter( ..so on) but does't recognize `indexOf` as I'm trying to use that inside the filter function. what do i do?

Comment: 1. `.map` operator returns one single object, no need to assign
2. you may want to return `return { 
    ...item,
    lower: item.label.toLowerCase(),
    offsetString: 'something',
  };`

Comment: I need to reassign I need the index key to be a string

Comment: @swoopy the index of...what? You've declared `TIMEZONE_NAME_MAP` as `TimezoneListType[]` which means an *array*. Arrays' indexes are positive integers, not arbitrary strings. Moreover, your `.map` doesn't strictly perform a mapping operation - while TS might not complain about that (not actually sure), *I would* were I to do your code review. I'm sure many other people also would. I'd also take the opportunity to point out that `const hour = item.offset | 0;` is *most likely* incorrect. You might have meant `||` in which case you have a typo. If you did mean `|`, then offsets can be fractions.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment on the last line implies a for loop may be better suited to this scenario than a map. The purpose of the map is to create an array mapped to new values corresponding to the original, whereas your goal here is to create a dictionary.

PS, you also don’t seem to be using the values that you create during the mapping anywhere after assigning them (positive, minute)

Comment: Im using them at `offsetString` i just removed it and place 'something' for simplicity

Comment: Noted. As for the mapping, let me phrase it in a different way. The purpose of the map method is to perform a mapping rather than to create a map. It’s mapping the values at the indexes of your array to the values at the index of a new array, rather than creating a map (dictionary in your case) that implicitly handles the mapping when provided a key.

Answer (score 0):

Your getting that error because you are assigning an object to the array index and it is expecting you to an numeric index.

```
const TIMEZONE_MAP = TIMEZONE_LIST.map((item) => { 
  const positive = item.offset >= 0;
  const hour = item.offset | 0;
  const minute = (item.offset - hour) * 60;
  return TIMEZONE_NAME_MAP[index] = {  // typescript is screaming in this line.
    ...item,
    lower: item.label.toLowerCase(),
    offsetString: 'something',
  };
  });
```

EDIT: this would be a better way:

```
const TIMEZONE_MAP = TIMEZONE_LIST.map((item, index) => {
  const positive = item.offset >= 0;
  const hour = item.offset | 0;
  const minute = (item.offset - hour) * 60;
  return  {  // typescript is screaming in this line.
    ...item,
    lower: item.label.toLowerCase(),
    offsetString: 'something',
  };
  });
```

Edit 2 as per new requirement:

```
const TIMEZONE_MAP = TIMEZONE_LIST.map((item, index) => {
  const positive = item.offset >= 0;
  const hour = item.offset | 0;
  const minute = (item.offset - hour) * 60;
  let obj = {};
  obj[item.name] = {...item,
    lower: item.label.toLowerCase(),
    offsetString: 'something'};
  return  obj;
  });
```

Comment: but i want that to be string ideal result of TIMEZONE_MAP would be [item.name]{ key: value}

Comment: @swoopy, please give an example of the expected output

Comment: [string]: { ...item, lower: 'value', offsetString: 'value', }

Comment: @swoopy, [string] is a single string but you assigning a object

Comment: okay, what would i assign to make it so the indexes of the array object is a string?

Comment: @swoopy you cant. see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526860/why-does-a-string-index-in-an-array-not-increase-the-length

Comment: okay, so I'll just change my object container to `const TIMEZONE_NAME_MAP: TimezoneListType[] = {};` how would you type it?

Comment: getting there, how would you type `item` and the `obj` - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205861/discussion-between-vince-and-swoopy).

Answer (score 0):

`.map` operator returns one single object, no need to assign

```
const TIMEZONE_NAME_MAP: TimezoneListType[] = TIMEZONE_LIST.map((item) => {
  const positive = item.offset >= 0;
  const hour = item.offset | 0;
  const minute = (item.offset - hour) * 60;
  return { 
    ...item,
    lower: item.label.toLowerCase(),
    offsetString: 'something',
  };
});
```

Comment: but this will result on indexes being numbers, I want the indexes to be string with the value of `item.name`

Comment: @swoopy if you want the indexes to be strings, then you don't want an array.

Comment: @VLAZ, i supposed - I've changed the declaration to const TIMEZONE_NAME_MAP: any = {} , how would you change the any to fit the typing?