# computed property returns empty array

Tags: vuejs2, computed-properties

I have a computed property in VueJS like this:

```
  computed: {
    groupedTemplates() {
      const ret = this.templates.reduce((acc, value) => {
        value.group = value.group || "Ungrouped";
        if (!acc[value.group]) {
          acc[value.group] = [];
        }
        acc[value.group].push(value);
        return acc;
      }, []);
      console.log(ret);   // <---- This works!!
      return ret;
    },
    ...mapState(["currentPatient", "currentSite", "phrases", "templates"]),
  },
```

When I view the console, I can see the correct response which is
`app.js:4061 [Ungrouped: Array(6), Note: Array(2), Order Set: Array(3)]`

However, when I use `groupedTemplates` in code, it evaluates to `[]`

when I change the return line to

```
return 34;
```

It returns 34 as expected. What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `reduce` does not add items into the array but creating new **properties** on `Array` object - you can't [use a string as an index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526860/why-does-a-string-index-in-an-array-not-increase-the-length) into an array...

What you probably want is to return `Object` from your `groupedTemplates` computed...

Comment: Wow! great pick up! Thanks! But how come I was able to see it with console.log?

Comment: Console just shows object with all the properties....