# Why do javascript arrays allow me to use a string as a key index?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Why do javascript arrays allow me to use a string as a key index?

For example,

```
let r = [];
r['test'] = 'testvalue' // [testvalue: 321]
```

Arrays can be used like objects. Is that because everything in Javascript is an object, is that why arrays have that object-like functionality?

Comment: *because everything in Javascript is an object* Except primitives, but yes

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9526860/why-does-a-string-index-in-an-array-not-increase-the-length