# How to push to mongoose objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

cannot add additional objects into object list.

i have a schema that follows

```
apps: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
    default: [],
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  registeredDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
  }
```

i am able to add to apps object by doing something like

```
user = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username });
user.apps[req.body.id] = {
   isUser: false,
   order: null,
};

await user.save()
```

This work for the first object.

But if i want to add another object instance inside apps again, i try the same code which works on NodeJS, i am able to see it in console.log(), but when i login to my database, i can only see the first object that was added. How would i be able to push any additional objects?

Thank you

Comment: What is, and why do you use `req.body.id` to index `user.apps`?

Comment: `user.apps[req.body.id]` is [setting a property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9526896/1409374) of `user.apps`, not increasing the _"data storage"_ of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add another object instance inside apps`

you need use query `update|| updateOne` to add new object with operator [$push](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push)

```
await user.updateOne(
  { username: req.body.username },
  {
    $push: { apps: {
        key1Example: 'valueExample1',
        key2Example: 'valueExample2',
    } },
  }
);
```

try it in [MONGO-PLAYGROUND](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ElBmVC-c_2C)

Comment: so i have to write the existing objects + the one i am trying to add?

Comment: you dont need it, only a new one.

Comment: Also i tried that but nothing updates :(

Comment: I tried this, it doesnt give me any errors but it doesnt change anything either.

await user.updateOne(
          { username: req.body.username },
          {
            $push: {
              apps: {
                [req.body.id]: {
                  isUser: false,
                  order: null,
                },
              },
            },
          }

Comment: i just tried the query, it works, i added [mongo-playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ElBmVC-c_2C)

Comment: i had to use User schema instead of the user instance i created. it worked thank you for you help